# Why can't I share project files with another QGIS user?

Tags: qgis

I am working with another QGIS user at a separate location and we want to share the projects that I have already created using QGIS. However, the other user is unable to open the project files in QGIS. This problem has occurred when sharing via USB stick or via files shared in Dropbox.

Could there be an issue with the fact that I installed the standalone version of 1.8.0 whilst my colleague installed the OSGeo4W version?

Comment: What issues are you running into?  Layers not loading?

Comment: From experience I found that if user A builds a project and includes a layer from the OpenLayers plugin and user B doesn't have the same plugin installed, then user B won't be able to open the project.

Comment: dropbox's folder can be located in different locations on each computer. ensure you have relative paths configured and all data is in subfolder of project location

Answer (score 6):

If the other user can't load some or all layers, you should switch file paths to relative under `Settings -> Project settings, General` tab, and move all loadable files into the same folder as the project file before adding them to the project.

Loading of WMS services or database connections might still be another issue.